# Function check Caesar cipher Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to words. They have tehe same lenght. I want to check if the second word is encoded with a Caesar cipher correctly. I wrote a simple function, but sometimes it works but sometimes not. I dont know what is wrong.
This may code:

```
def check_Ceaesar(word1, word2):
    t=word1
    s=word2
    k=ord(s[0])-ord(t[0])
    if k>0:
        k=ord(s[0])-ord(t[0])

    else: k=26+(ord(s[0])-ord(t[0]))

    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        if ord(t[i])<ord(s[i]):
            temp=ord(s[i])-ord(t[i])
        else: temp=26+(ord(s[i])-ord(t[i]))

        if temp!=k:
            return "YES"
            break
        else:
            return "NO"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `'NO'` if `temp` is not equal to `k` instead, and wait for the loop to finish before returning `'YES'`.

Change:

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):

    if ord(t[i])<ord(s[i]):
        temp=ord(s[i])-ord(t[i])
    else: temp=26+(ord(s[i])-ord(t[i]))

    if temp!=k:
        return "YES"
        break
    else:
        return "NO"
```

to:

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):

    if ord(t[i])<ord(s[i]):
        temp=ord(s[i])-ord(t[i])
    else: temp=26+(ord(s[i])-ord(t[i]))

    if temp!=k:
        return "NO"
return "YES"
```

You can also check that the differences between the ordinary numbers of the corresponding letters of the two words after taking the modulo of 26 are of only one number by converting them to a set and checking that the length of the set is 1:

```
def check_Ceaesar(word1, word2):
    return len({(ord(a) - ord(b)) % 26 for a, b in zip(word1, word2)}) == 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to do it that in simple way. What is it wrong with my code. I've started programming in Python so I dont want to use for example "zip".